# Find correlations between genes and samples

Tags: python, r, statistics, correlation

I have data with samples as rows and Genes as columns with gene expression values.

The original data has more than 100 genes. Below is an example of a data frame.

```
df <- data.frame (Sample  = c("A1", "A2", "A3", "B1", "B2", "B3"),
                  Group = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"),
                  geneA = c(1, 2, 1, 19, 24, 18), 
                  geneB = c(15, 15, 14, 40, 39, 36), 
                  geneC = c(11, 10, 10, 45, 52, 39), 
                  geneD = c(25, 23, 26, 54, 54, 57), 
                  geneE = c(43, 42, 48, 164, 166, 155))
```

And I want to get the correlation as a table like this (columns and rows represent group and gene names).

| Gene | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| GeneA | 0.763 | 0.231 |
| GeneB | 0.998 | -0.435 |
| GeneC | 0.876 | 0.002 |
| GeneD | 0.453 | -0.345 |
| GeneE | 0.544 | 0.987 |
| ... | 0.987 | ... |

Thank you!!

***Edit//

For clarification, I'd like to get a result similar to this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKpYQ.png)

Source: https://doi.org/10.3389/fpls.2022.820439

Comment: It is unclear what are you trying to correlate? First of all all you column results are just GeneA and secondly all your groups only contain 1 item each